# How to find correspondence of versions between vscode and monaco-editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

In [monaco-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor) it states:

> Please note that this repository contains no source code for the code editor, it only contains the scripts to package everything together and ship the monaco-editor npm module

and

> The Monaco Editor is generated straight from VS Code's sources with some shims around services the code needs to make it run in a web browser outside of its home.

I'm trying to find the exact version that was sourced from vscode (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode). For example, what's the corresponding vscode version for the monaco-editor [0.21.2](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/v0.21.2)?

I looked at `metadata.js` and `package.json` but it wasn't clear to me.

Context: I have a legacy version of monaco (0.21.2) which I'm trying to read the source code from.